# check if the map has a specific string in it's keys, then give me it's value, that belong this key, Dart

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

may i ask how to check if the map of String,String has in it's keys a specific String
then i want to get the value that belong this specific key that contains the target String.
for example
this Map

```
Map<String, String> ListFinalAllInfos = {'stackoverflow': 'one', 'google': 'two'};
```

and i want to check if this map has this String in it's keys

```
stackoverflow
```

if stackoverflow exists as a key inside the map then i want to get the value
which is

```
one
```

without converting the map to a list, if this possible.
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you means not to call `toList()` anywhere?

Comment: thanks for your help. yes i don't want to convert the map to list by calling toList()
is there any solution without calling toList() ?

Comment: Do you just want to get the value `one` from the key `stackoverflow`?

Comment: like listFinalAllInfos['stackoverflow']?

Comment: yes exactly i just want to get the value of the key that contains stackoverflow

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> ListFinalAllInfos = {'stackoverflow': 'one', 'google': 'two'};
String key = ListFinalAllInfos.containsKey("stackoverflow"); // search for the key. for example stackoverflow
String value = ListFinalAllInfos[key]; // get the value for the key, value will be 'one'
if(ListFinalAllInfos.containsKey(value)){ //check if there is a key which is the value you grabbed
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `String key = ListFinalAllInfos.containsKey("stackoverflow");`
Should be :
`bool keyExists = ListFinalAllInfos.containsKey("stackoverflow");`  
though then we need to add condition for keyexists..
And then:
`String value = ListFinalAllInfos[key];`
Should be :
`String value = ListFinalAllInfos["stackoverflow"];`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [containsKey(Object? key)](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/Map/containsKey.html) method of map to know whether it is having a matching key. This method returns true if this map contains the given [key]. So in context to your question, to check whether map has this key just use:

```
final hasKey = listFinalAllInfos.containsKey("stackoverflow");
```

Now you know whether the map has the key or not. Based on that, to get value of respective key just use:

```
final valueOfKey = listFinalAllInfos["stackoverflow"];
```

This will return you the value associated to the key in the map.